# Is there any possibility to change Undergrad track from Film and Media Studies to Communication department that is focused on more computational?

Tags: masters, data, social-science

I want to pursue my master's in Communication that is more analytical and research-oriented and based on computational methods. Film and media recognize the area of the internet, social media, audiences/users, broadcast policy, law, technical priorities but with no 'data' related works or method. On the other hand, I have technically finished some data science-related courses like web scraping, quantitative/statistical analysis, python, SPSS, and tableau. After learning them (as a beginner and with no experience), I am trying to work on related areas, and I am very much curious to learn further. Specifically, I would love to enter into the world of computational social science, media analytics, social data and object-oriented programming to produce the more critical and analytical. Also, I found that my interest is not only based on Media but also on the Internet, Information and Technology. Can I be able to shift?

Comment: You need to explore this locally unless you want to change universities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media studies departments can and do include computational media.  Some departments may be called communications, others media studies or science and technology studies. The purpose of a MA degree can be to go into a more detailed area of study than your BA. See if there’s any faculty at your current college who might be knowledgeable about or have a focus in computational media, software studies, or German media theory. To start, you may want to look at the work of scholars like Wendy Chun, Jacob Gaboury, or Saifya Noble. However this is just to start: talk to faculty at your own college first.

Comment: You point out that the person may get what they are looking for in their current department, but I would also try to comment on their direct question about changing departments.

Comment: Yes, they are also welcome to switch departments, especially if there is one at their university. The OP doesn't state which department they would be more interested in at their current school, but that would be helpful to know.